# Django model multiply filter

Tags: django, django-models

I want to filter my model object using two filters.
So, it can be only one filter or both or none.
My solution is to use a lot of 'if':

```
if _topic or _curator:
    if _topic and _curator:
        queryset = Article.objects.filter(topic=_topic,curator=_curator)
    elif _curator:
        queryset = Article.objects.filter(curator=_curator)
    else # so topic is the last choice
        queryset = Article.objects.filter(topic=_topic)
else
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
```

Can someone suggest an easier way to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queryset filters are cumulative.

```
queryset = Article.objects.all()
if _topic:
    queryset = queryset.filter(topic=_topic)
if _curator:
    queryset = queryset.filter(curator=_curator)
```

Comment: okay, my bad, i thought: "if it is no topic in the database then this will return nothing even if it was a curator in the DB". But now i realized that my filter is made by me by clicking on the topic or on the curator at the article) so it can't be nothing in the resultset)

Answer (score 1):

```
kwargs = {}
if _topic:
    kwargs[topic] = _topic
if _curator:
    kwargs[curator] = _curator
queryset = Article.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```